# ffmpeg smooth motion overlay image without jitter

Tags: image, animation, ffmpeg, overlay, motion

When I try any animation of overlayed image (just simple left-to-rigth motion) it's jitter and laggy
[Plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u37VZ.png)

I rendered three examples in [one video](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AinXcDaDEbPihYZ3KmjswwhSWyCD9A?e=0H8Na1) to demonstrate how it works in deafault in Premiere, Davinci, and ffmpeg
How to remove this jitter and achieve smooth animation like in Premiere or DaVinci?

My filter-command is

```
ffmpeg -i VIDEO -loop 1 -i IMAGE -filter_complex "[0:v][1]overlay=shortest=1:x=95+t*(W-w)/624:y=180[v2]" -map [v2] -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 16M -t 15 -y out.mp4
```

1. x1 = 95
2. x2 = end of screen
3. y - is constant
4. Duration of video - 624s

I think the problem is in formula (x=95+t*(W-w)/624) or maybe I should use frames, not time
I've tryed to add -r 30 before image. It not helped
I've tryed to use tblend or minterpolation. It not helped.

Link to video: https://1drv.ms/v/s!AinXcDaDEbPihYZ3KmjswwhSWyCD9A?e=0H8Na1

Comment: i have an idea. maybe, increase fps and size: `scale=3840:2160,fps=120[v]; [v][1]overlay=x=95+n*(W-w...` more pixels and frames, smoother motion?

Comment: It not helped. The plane still move laggy. not smooth.

Comment: overlay freezes on 1st frame and jumps by 2 pixels on 2nd frame. it is not normal. imho, better move pic using other method. best result for overlay was: `[0:v]fps=100[v];[v][1]overlay=shortest=1:x=95+n/2:y=180,fps=25`

Comment: tried to move pic by geq: `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i plane.png -filter_complex "pad=1280:720:95:180:black@0,geq=r='r(X-N,Y)':g='g(X-N,Y)':b='b(X-N,Y)':a='alpha(X-N,Y)'" -c:v ffv1 -pix_fmt yuva420p -t 15 -y out.mkv` it looks better, but cant change speed of plane